# how to display data from razor pay api in table php

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

There are two files

The first one is `php_ifsc.php` and the second one is `getdata.php`

I have made a form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>php

    </title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <table class="table">
      
    <table>
    <form method="post">

        <label>
            ifsc:
            <input type="text" name="ifsc" id="ifsc" placeholder="Enter Ifsc Code">
        </label>
        <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit" >
    </form>
</body>

<Script>
 $('#submit').click(function(){
      var ifsc=$('#ifsc').val();
    //   alert(getdata);
       $.ajax({
        url:"getdata.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{
            'ifsc1':true,
            'ifsc':ifsc
        },

        success:function(response){
           
          $.each(response,function(value,key){
            var Html="<tr>\
                <td>"+response[i].key+"</td>\
                <td>"+response[i].key+"</td>\
            </tr>;"
            $('.table').append(Html);  
            
          });
          }})
        
    
    })

</script>
```

In which in order to take input as Ifsc code? I have successfully taken input through ajax and php but i want to show this data in table which is getting from this api https://ifsc.razorpay.com/

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ifsc1'])){
    $ifsc=$_POST['ifsc'];
    $get_api=@file_get_contents('https://ifsc.razorpay.com/'.$ifsc);
    $json_decode=json_decode($get_api);


    if(isset($json_decode->ADDRESS)){
        // print_r($json_decode->ADDRESS);
        // print_r($json_decode->BANK);
        return json_decode($get_api,true);
    }
    else{
        echo "invalid ifsc code";
    }    
}



?>
```

and fetch this data from this api and show in show in table and this api will give data when we will enter ifsc code. But i am not able to print this data.